# INNER JOIN com SOMA - SQL

Tags: sql, excel-vba, microsoft-access

**Bom dia**!

Tenho duas tabelas no access que me apresentam CPF e valor, porém não estou conseguindo juntar as duas tabelas somando a quantia. Como não entendo de access, estou tentando fazer a consulta via SQL (que por sinal também não tenho tanto conhecimento):

Ex.:

```
CPF (tabela1)                         CPF (tabela2)
----------------------                ----------------------
12345678910     10,00                 12345678910     9,00
01987654321     20,00                 01987654321     20,00
```

A consulta na verdade seria subtrair um campo do outro e retornar tudo o que fosse diferente de zero. No exemplo da tabela, ele teria que me mostrar a primeira linha com o valor de 1,00 e não trazer a segunda linha.

```
SELECT CPF, vlrTRAN 
FROM Arqtxt 
INNER JOIN Arqtxt2 ON Arqtxt.[CPF] = Arqtxt2.NumCpf;
```

Comment: Corrigindo o código: SELECT CPF, vlrTRAN FROM Arqtxt INNER JOIN Arqtxt2 ON Arqtxt.[CPF] = Arqtxt2.NumCpf;

Comment: você pode editar a pergunta (já coloquei esse código no lugar do outro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução apresentada é para as duas tabelas abaixo, mesmo problema apresentado so mudando o nome das tabelas e o nome das colunas.

```
**tabela1**
cpf         valor
12345678910   10
01987654321   20


**tabela2**
cpf          valor
12345678910  9
01987654321  20
```

Query sql:

```
SELECT t1.cpf, t1.valor, (t1.valor - t2.valor) as diferenca 
FROM tabela1  as t1
INNER JOIN tabela2 as t2 ON t1.cpf = t2.cpf
where (t1.valor - t2.valor) > 0
```

Primeiro de tudo coloque alias para as tabelas, isso evita ambiguidade na consulta pois, as tabelas tem as colunas com o mesmo nome. Faça a subtração da coluna valor da tabela1(t1) e tabela2(t2).
No final coloque um `where` para filtrar somente valores maiore que 0

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu precisava! Muito obrigado Bernardo, salvou o meu dia!!!! Vou estudar mais para chegar em uma conclusão de forma tão simples quanto a que você chegou!!!! Valeu

Comment: [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com) é bom pra estudar sql

Comment: Edit: uma outra dúvida... eu consigo mostrar também o que não tem em ambas as tabelas? Ex. ter três CPF's em uma e dois na outra?

Comment: @DouglasSilva é possivel sim. Faz uma pesquisa no google  "except sql", que encontra muita coisa